# Interpolate a discrete vector field

Tags: interpolation, vector

I have a discrete vector field, from which I want to derive the continuous one. For example, the planar vector field is defined by:

```
discreteVectorField = 
Table[{x, y, Normalize[{Cos[x], Tan[y]}] // N}, {x, 1, 3, 1}, {y, 1, 3, 1}];
```

How to interpolate the data? 
(When I try to draw this vector field, I noticed that `ListVectorPlot` by default interpolates the data given. Could I use the interpolation function?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dVF = Table[{{x, y}, Normalize@{Cos@x, Tan@y}}, {x, 1, 3, 1}, {y, 1,  3, 1}];
f = Interpolation@Flatten[dVF, 1];
VectorPlot[f[x, y], {x, 1, 3}, {y, 1, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Could you add the plot of the original vector field *before* interpolation @Dr.belisarius? So that we can compare before/after? (I don't have Mathematica here so I cannot run it, but it's just for general knowledge about vector field interp.)